# How to define a Bi-Directional bus as 'z' or as '0,1' in One Line?

Tags: verilog

I'm using the altera synthesizer with a 32-bit bi-directional bus :

```
module Test
(
   inout  [31:0]biBus
);

wire [31:0] biEna;
wire [31:0] biVal;
```

I'm wondering if there's a syntax that instead of doing this:

```
assign biBus [ 0 ]  = biEna [ 0 ] ? biVal [ 0 ] : 1'bz;
assign biBus [ 1 ]  = biEna [ 1 ] ? biVal [ 1 ] : 1'bz;
...
assign biBus [ 31 ]  = biEna [ 31 ] ? biVal [ 31 ] : 1'bz;
```

could instead be done in 1 line, something like:

```
assign biBus  = biEna ? biVal : *'bz;
```

Where each bit of the bus is assigned either biVal or hi-z based on the corresponding value of biEna.    How would I specify the hi-z portion above (if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in an `always_comb` or `always @*` block:

```
integer i;
for (i = 31 ; i >=0 ; i--)
    if (biEna[i]) biBus[i] = biVal[i];
    else biBus[i] = 1'bz;
```

or:

```
biBus = 'z; //Initialize all bits to z
for (i = 31 ; i >=0 ; i--)
    if (biEna[i]) biBus[i] = biVal[i]; //Overwrite the z value for bits whose enable is 1
```

or if you want to keep using assign statements without an always block:

```
genvar i;
for (i=31 ; i>=0 ; i--)
   assign biBus [ i ]  = biEna [ i ] ? biVal [ i ] : 1'bz;
```

Comment: From my experience tri-state drivers work best with `assign`. I have seen simulators give incorrect results when the `'bz` is assigned by always blocks and does not show 'x' when when there are conflicting drivers on the bus.

Answer (score 1):

Just `{32{1'bZ}}` or `32'hZZZZZZZZ`.

Comment: I nearly suggested this but the tristates is at the bit level not for the full 32bit bus.

Comment: {32{1'bZ}} clones single-bit 1'bZ 32 times thus giving you 32 tristated bits. The same way every Z in 32'**h**ZZZZZZZZ gives you 4 tristated bits.